# gridview binding error even column is present in dataset

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am getting following error on gridview binding.
`DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Sr'`.

In my gridview itemtemplete i have a lable like this.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblQuesNo" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Sr.No.") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Sr.No. is present in dataset.

Comment: error says you define column in gridview sr wwhich not present which i think rightbcz you have  sr.no. not sr

Comment: Show your dataset code lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
<asp:Label ID="lblQuesNo" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Container.DataItem, "Sr.No.") %>'></asp:Label>
```